# Estimating BKZ block size in Kyber

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, kyber

In Section 5.2.1 of the [Kyber documentation](https://pq-crystals.org/kyber/data/kyber-specification-round3-20210131.pdf), it states that the BKZ block size of 413 was chosen using the tool from [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/292), i.e., [this tool](https://github.com/lducas/leaky-LWE-Estimator). How was the block size derived from this? Currently, inputting

```
n=512
m=512
q=3329
D_e = build_centered_binomial_law(2)
D_s = build_centered_binomial_law(3)
```

building a DBDD instance and estimating the attack complexity gives $\beta$ = 393.29.

Comment: Look at the [NIST-round3](https://github.com/lducas/leaky-LWE-Estimator/blob/NIST-round3/NIST-round3/kyber-bkz.sage#L5-L21) branch in that repository.